# How to disable strict MySql?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have my own portals developed using PHP and MySql. It was working well for some months. But now it throws some kind of mysql errors like "Incorrect datetime value : '' for appointment", "Set default value for" etc. Because of these I'm unable to process.

Is there any settings to overcome this issue?

Comment: Did your host (or you) upgrade your version of MYSQL to 5.7?

Comment: Can you post the exact error messages and the code that displaying the errors? Thank you

Comment: Have you recently upgraded your MySQL version to 5.7? They recently got stricter with accepting bad values by default.
Maybe have a look at the [NO_ZERO_DATE mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_zero_in_date) setting.

Comment: If you did upgrade to 5.7 then you should read all [the upgrade notes here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/upgrading-from-previous-series.html)

Comment: This is the current MYSQL Server version: 5.6.31 - MySQL Community Server (GPL). I didn't upgrade also I asked the hosting provider about this. They said, so far nothing have been updated

Answer (score 0):

You are using different version of PHP. Remove default value (current time stamp) of that column and set it explicitly from the application.

Comment: I've set default value as None. But it says me to set as NULL.

Comment: Yes. It's working fine. But I have many internal portals so find difficult to change in all DBs.